# UnsatisfiedLinkError in lotus-notes plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, java-native-interface, lotus-notes

We are having an issue with a dll in a notes plugin.

When we call this:
NotesFactory.createSession();

we get this error:

Unable to create view: nlsxbe (The filename or extension is too long.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nlsxbe (The filename or extension is too long. ) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:952) 
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:921) 
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:452) 
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.load(Unknown Source) 
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.checkLoaded(Unknown Source) 
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.sinitThread(Unknown Source) 
at com.atempo.adam.lotus.plugin.views.TopicView.createPartControl(TopicView.java:609)

NotesFactory is in Notes.jar, that we have included in our "plugin.xml" in dependencies tab. (The dependencie is: "com.ibm.notes.java.api").

The path to the jar is: 
"C:\Archivos de programa\IBM\Lotus\Notes\framework\rcp\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.rcp.j2se.win32.x86_1.5.0.SR4-200707311521\jre\lib\Notes.jar" 
That is longer than 128 characters.
If we install notes in "c:\program files\IBM" instead of "C:\Archivos de programa\IBM", the resulting path is shorter than 128 and we don't get the error.

We have also tried copying nlsxbe.dll to WIN\System32 or registring nlsxbe.dll with the regsvr32 command, but we get the same error.

Versions are:
Lotus notes 8.0, Revision 20070803.1143
java 1.5.0

thanks

Comment: Due to the utter horribleness of Lotus Notes, I suspect you will get few replies! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `nlsxbe` path to your Environment variables. It Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jar as an External jar to the plugin project?  If so try copying the jar and the dll into to the plugin project and reference them from there.

You can try asking Mikkel for some help he has lots of experience with plugin development within Lotus Notes --> www.lekkimworld.com

Comment: Hello Carlos, thanks very much for reply.
Yes, i've tried to add Notes.jar as an external jar, but then i get an error saying that the thread that i build to create my client Session is already created by Lotus for his Session, and in other forum i read that the solution was put this dependencie (com.ibm.notes.java.api) that includes Notes.jar.

Answer (score 0):

@Carlos
Jaime wrote me an e-mail and sure I will answer.

@Mitch Wheat
I don't know if you've seen Notes recently but since Notes 8 was released this is no longer your grand fathers Notes!! Notes is now based on Eclipse and a very modern and capable client. Probably one of the strongest enterprise clients, if not the strongest, on the market today.
Many with views like yours either haven't seen (or used) a Notes client for a looooooong time or they are part of an organization that simply don't upgrade due to reasons that are beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Notes.jar should be in the "Notes\jvm\lib\ext" folder. Use that one instead. There are known issues putting the Notes.jar into your plugin that can cause the client to crash/fail.